# Excel Power Query: how to prevent multiple requests for the same source (web json)?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a REST endpoint that queries the data in JIRA and returns the data for **activeSprint** and **previousSprint** so the user can build a burndown chart, similar to this:

```json
{
   activeSprint: ['..burndown data array..'],
   previousSprint: ['..burndown data array..'] 
}
```

So in power query I setup the first query which is only representing the connection-only to the source

**JSON**

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://.../burndown"))
in
    Source
```

Then I make a `reference` of the query called JSON and create a new query called **Active Sprint**

```
let
    Source = JSON,
    activeSprint = Source[activeSprint],
    burndownData = activeSprint[burndownData],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(burndownData, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"date", "dateFormatted", "storyPoints", "issueCount", "issues", "plannedStoryPoints"}, {"date", "dateFormatted", "storyPoints", "issueCount", "issues", "plannedStoryPoints"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"dateFormatted", type datetime}, {"date", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

then I do the same as per above for the **Previous Sprint** query.

I group all the queries together in XLS into one group called **TEST1** so it looks like this:
[image]

When I right click on the group **Test1** and click refresh, it makes **2 requests** to the API. Can I make it just one call since the source is the same for both ??

The dependency in the Power Query Editor is correct, but I don't get it why it sends 2 separate requests ??

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can't unless you change design in your queries. Problem is, that PQ removes middle steps from memory (there is no reason to hold it). However I think you could utilize `List.Buffer` or `Table.Buffer` if you are able to do all of that in one query.

Comment: Hi Michal, well, the response basically carries the data for 2 different tables that the users are planning to build the charts on. Is there a way to create 2 datasources from one query ? I still consider this being a fundamental flaw that the connection cannot hold the data temporarily for all the queries that reference this 'query' until they are finished.

Comment: I've ended up with writing my own backend service that caches the results (nodejs + expressjs + rxdb + jira connector)

Comment: If you find solution, feel free to post it as your own answer (for future generations).